# Is there a way to delete all entries?

Tags: content, deletion

Starting on a second site which is an almost like for like copy of the first, except it has different content. I cant use locales to manage it because there may be the possibility of multiple languages on the second site.

I have dozens of field & entry types I want to transfer over to the second site. Is there an automated way of deleting all the content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also delete all rows in your `craft_elements` table, which have `type` set to `Entry` (or whatever [ElementType](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) you want to delete).

Comment: This is a great answer. Deleting an element from the `craft_elements` table will properly cascade and automatically delete any related rows in other tables.

Comment: How does this cascade? Is this a MySQL feature I don't know about? Thanks.

Comment: Evidently it must be. I deleted all "Entry" rows from craft_elements and sure enough it emptied out all other relevant tables. Thanks for the suggestion. I'd love to know how that works if anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out somewhat by using the [Import plugin, by Bob Olde Hampsink](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import), exporting all my slugs to a csv, then using the delete functionality of the plugin to remove all entries with a slug found in the csv. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

On a related task, if you want to just empty out a section or type, delete queries in the `entries` table matching on `sectionId` or `typeId` fields. This  also cascades. Then you can keep your other sections, especially singles, which otherwise force you to delete and recreate the section to restore the single type entry.

EDIT: After doing this and batch importing data, I noticed the slugs were generated as duplicates (added integer on the end). Sure enough, `elements_i18n` wasn't cleared out like `entries` and `elements` tables. So you'll have to change the query to delete rows from both tables or use the first method above and somehow filter for the sectionId you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only do that by deleting and recreating a section.