# Delete entries from database

Tags: craft3

I believe I made a mistake by creating about 15,000 entries in a Structure section. It has caused a lot of problems and so I decided to start again with a Channel section instead. I tried deleting the old section to remove the entries but it crashes mysql. Does anyone know a way to remove entries and their content in the database?

Comment: It might be too late for that but you could have converted your structure to a channel and it would have kept your entries

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try that first but I think due to the amount of entries I got an endless amount of resaving and reindexing in the queue. Also because of the relation with the parent, I decided I was likely going to have to reenter the entries anyway with a different relation(like entry or category).

Answer (score 1):

I think I did this successfully with help from another answer on [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-entries). I removed the data from the craft_elements table by using the fieldLayoutId column to identify the entry type I wanted to remove. Seems it removed the data from the other tables as well.